# Partial Differential Equations - Error Functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, error-function

So I am doing a course this semester in PDEs and we are currently doing the heat/diffusion equation $(u_t +ku_{xx}=0)$ on the whole line and the half line. In solving these equations we have introduced the *error function*,$$\operatorname{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt.$$

My question is

> What exactly is the *error function* and why is it natural or useful to express a solution to a PDE in terms of it?

I understand that it is closely related to the normal cdf
$$ P(N < x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2/2}dt$$
but it doesn't seem to make a lot of sense when solving PDEs. I'm just questioning why, when I have a perfectly good solution, do I have to then go and make substitutions and change my limits of integration just to put it in terms of this *error function*. I have to assume that there is some logic behind this and that it was not invented just to annoy students in the future, like myself.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: It is useful to express a solution to a PDE in terms of it because it directly relates to the [fundamental solution of the heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel). See also [here](http://www.uccs.edu/~rcarlson/math447/heateq.pdf).